# How to convert a string to an int or decimal?

Tags: c#, decimal

I have this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the price of the product?"); 
Decimal price = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I take a input as a string as either a int or/and decimal number and convert it to a variable. Or well, that is my intention. The input is a price of a product and it can have decimals or it cannot.  I you only type in ints, it works, but with decimals it crashes. I'm new to this and I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: What exactly are you typing into console window?

Comment: By crash, what do you mean.  Please show stack trace or at least the Exception message.

Comment: "it crashes" isn't enough information. Please show your input, and the exception.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a separator matching the culture that the program expects? `11,5` will work on some systems and `11.5` on others.

Comment: @ Theodoros That did it, when I enter a number with a comma, it works, but not when I use a dot. God i feel so stupid.

Comment: @Baxtex You can supply a `CultureInfo` parameter to `Parse` if you want the program to control which character is accepted (instead of depending on the user's system's settings).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prevent exception:

```
while (true)
{
     string input = Console.ReadLine();
     decimal result;
     if (decimal.TryParse(input, out result))
     {
          // do your work
          break;
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("invalid value try again");
     }
}
```

Also I have used `while` loop to force user to enter correct value.If you don't want it you can ignore the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways how achieve this. For example:

```
string Input = Console.ReadLine();
Decimal InputConvertedAsDecimal;
if (Decimal.TryParse(Input, out InputConvertedAsDecimal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inputted number is: " + InputConvertedAsDecimal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error! Input have a incorrect format to parse.");
}
```